# Highcharts: stacked bar chart with different ranges of scales

Tags: highcharts, stacked-chart

I have an example of a stacked bar chart with different ranges of scales. In the example below, you will see, that it looks not so good and it is impossible to see the Sales.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Leads',
    data: [20, 20, 30, 20, 10]
}, {
    name: 'Clicks',
    data: [3000, 4000, 4000, 2000, 5000]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x3teouks/

Is there a way to transform the data, so we can display all the data in a good way for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `minPointLength` property for the series:

```
series: [{
    minPointLength: 4,
    ...
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d9p5jbrm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.minPointLength

Comment: Looks good! There is one problem only: https://jsfiddle.net/v3yhn5dw/
If I have something, what is 0, then it is displayed also, why?

Comment: Hi @Mutatos, That is due to setting the option. The simplest solution is to use `null` values insted of `0`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zvL4uypm/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Very strange feature with the null, but ok :-)